# Do git conflict resolution files not always represent every line in the source files?

Tags: c++, git, version-control, conflict

I'm working in a repo with three branches: master, stage, and dev. I've been working on dev for a while, am ready to push my changes, and have already squashed my local commits into a single commit for publishing. I want to update my local repo with any work that's been pushed to the remote's 'stage' branch by team members. I want to:

1. Pull any changes pushed to stage while I was working on dev
2. Rebase the single commit on 'dev' that represents my work onto 'stage'
3. Other stuff related to publishing

(Nobody else refers to my local dev branch, so I'm comfortable rebasing.)

I do:

```
git checkout stage
git pull
git checkout dev
```

Here's the situation:

**foo.cpp on branch dev (out of date)**

```
...
if (conditional)
{
    Datastructure data = someValue;
    cout << "Some text" << endl;
    cout << "More text" << endl;
}

return 0; // rest of function NYI

if (someOtherConditional) {

    Bob bob = makeBob();
    Fred fred = makeFred();
    ...
}
...
```

**foo.cpp on branch stage (more recent)**

```
...
if (conditional)
{
    Datastructure data = someValue;
    cout << "Some text" << endl;
    cout << "More text" << endl;

    cout << "Even more text" << endl;
    cout << "Lots of text" << endl;

    // todo: fix this hackish code
    if (anotherConditional) {
        myBool = true;
    }
}

if (yetAnotherConditional) {
    Bob bob = makeBob();
    Fred fred = makeFred();
    ...
}
...
```

Finally, I do:

```
git rebase stage
```

I get a few conflicts, including foo.cpp. I open foo.cpp up and get:

**foo.cpp after starting to rebase dev onto stage**

```
...
if (conditional)
{
    Datastructure data = someValue;
    cout << "Some text" << endl;
    cout << "More text" << endl;

<<<<<<<< HEAD
    cout << "Even more text" << endl;
    cout << "Lots of text" << endl;

    // todo: fix this hackish code
    if (anotherConditional) {
        myBool = true;
    }
}
=======
return 0; // rest of function NYI

if (someOtherConditional) {
>>>>>>> mostRecentDevCommit

if (yetAnotherConditional) {
    Bob bob = makeBob();
    Fred fred = makeFred();
    ...
}
...
```

What happened to the missing closing bracket matching the first `if (conditional) {` within `mostRecentDevCommit`?

And why is `if (yetAnotherConditional) {` outside the conflict-resolution section - foo.cpp on branch 'dev' doesn't have that!

Thanks - I actually don't need to figure this out to resolve the conflict, but I'd like to know what Git's doing here.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do for situations like this is to check the original, see what was there in the first place that made these two replacement hunks look like a minimal edit.

For future reference, you can ask for "diff3"-style conflict reporting, which will include the original hunk in the report, either on demand for specific files or as a default:

> `git -c merge.conflictstyle=diff3 checkout -m --`*`paths`*`# just these for now`
>   `git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3  # or as global default`

You can do a throwaway rerun of any merge or rebase by checking your reflogs, here `git reflog dev` will contain a pair like

```
9d7143d dev@{1}: rebase finished: refs/heads/dev onto 0f30b87ba7a2499c2b5d87b17d26ea8d353b8e34
5e58907 dev@{2}: commit: -
```

and with those numbers you'd

```
git -c merge.conflictstyle=diff3 rebase dev@{2} 0f30b87
# (look at foo.cpp, if the conflict report is still confusing, post it?)
git rebase --abort
git checkout @{-1}     # <-- takes you back to your previous checkout
```

---

Best I can come up with without that is perhaps it's (with maybe more lines deleted in both replacements):

```
    }
    return 0;
}

void func(type parm ...)
{
    if (someOtherConditional) {
```

which seems correct with all the three hunk versions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Checked original + my version + their version, still have no clue how git parsed them to get the replacement hunks above, resolved it by just using theirs.

Comment: As a favor to SO, could you post the diff3-style conflict report for that hunk (see how in my edit)?  I think this is a great example of what that config is for, it would make the q&a more valuable for others.  I wouldn't be much surprised if the original hunk was completely unlike my guess, so there's some personal curiosity in here too.